# How to schedule the update of access token (using refresh token), in node? (Please check answer.)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js

**Flow:**

- User attempts to login via Spotify (OAuth), and grants access to our web app (nodejs).
- `accessToken`, `refreshToken`, `expires_in` and `profile` data is returned in exchange for the Authorization Code. *(using Passport.js)*
- `accessToken`, `refreshToken` and some other data is stored on mongoDb Atlas (cloud), forming a Document. *(using mongoose)*
- The user logs out.
- The same user logs back in.
- `accessToken`, `refreshToken`, `expires_in` and `profile` data is returned in exchange for the Authorization Code.
- The Document in the cloud database, is not updated.

We are using these access tokens to create API calls in our main application `app.js`.

**Drawback:**

If the user logs out, and logs back in **after an hour**. He can no longer make API calls. The access token expires in an hour.

**Required update for the app:**

1. The access token, in our database should get updated every time the user logs in. (No new 'Document' or 'instance' of the same user should be created in our database.) ***[solved, check answer]***
2. The refresh token should update the value of access token, in our database, for first hour from login; then every hour afterwards for as long as the user stays logged in.
3. (Optional) If the user logs out and logs back in within one hour from latest access token, point '1' shouldn't execute, and the timer for point '2' shouldn't re-start.

---

**passport-setup.js:** This file is 'required' in 'app.js'.

```js
const passport = require("passport");
const SpotifyStrategy = require("passport-spotify").Strategy;
const keys = require("./keys");
const User = require("../models/user-model");

// Creating cookie
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
})

// Acccessing the created cookie
passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  User.findById(id).then((user) => {
    done(null, user);
  })
})

passport.use(
  new SpotifyStrategy({
    // Options for Spotify Strategy
    clientID: keys.spotify.clientID,
    clientSecret: keys.spotify.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: "/auth/spotify/redirect"
  }, (accessToken, refreshToken, expires_in, profile, done) => {
    // Passport callback function
    console.log("Reached Passport callback function, inside of 'passport-setup.js'.");

    // Check if user already exists in our database or if there is need to create a new one.
    User.findOne({
      spotifyId: profile.id
    }).then((existingUser) => {
      if (existingUser) {
        console.log("User already exists in database. Latest record:");
        console.log(existingUser);
        done(null, existingUser);
      } else {
        new User({
          displayName: profile.displayName,
          email: profile._json.email,
          spotifyId: profile.id,
          accessToken: accessToken,
          refreshToken: refreshToken
        }).save().then((newUser) => {
          console.log("New user created:");
          console.log(newUser);
          done(null, newUser);
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.log("Error occured: " + err);
        })
      }
    })
  })
)
```

---

*I tried referencing the official documentation for mongoose, and watched some tutorials online. But all I got returned with, was errors. Hence, seeking help. I'm an absolute beginner, any help would be appreciated. :)*

Answer (score 0):

**For first ("1.") required update,**

replace

```js
User.findOne({
      spotifyId: profile.id
    })
```

with

```js
User.findOneAndUpdate({
        spotifyId: profile.id
      }, {
        $set: {
          accessToken: accessToken,
          refreshToken: refreshToken
        }
      }, {
        new: true,
        useFindAndModify: false
      })
```

I am yet to find solution for the other points.

**Current progress:**

I'm aware we can use `node-cron` to schedule our tasks.

Following is the `POST` request for fetching access from Spotify.

```js
 axios({
   url: "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token",
   method: "post",
   params: {
     grant_type: "refresh_token",
     refresh_token: refresh_token      // I do not know how to input the database stored refreshToken here.
   },
   headers: {
     Authorization: authorization,
     "Accept": "application/json",
     "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
   }
 }).then(function(response) {
   // console.log(response.data);
   // console.log(response.data.access_token);
   let access_token = response.data.access_token;
   let token = "Bearer " + access_token;
   console.log(token);
 }).catch(function(error) {
   console.log(error);
 });
```